Cannot get elpy to find jedi in my venv even though it is installed via pip and via melpa
I've been struggling to setup a python IDE elpy in emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm running into issues.
I got a fresh install of Emacs (fixed the issues with expired GNU gpg keys) and installed elpy using M-x package-install RET elpy.
My ~/.emacs.d/init.el looks like so:
(require 'package)
(require 'use-package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :init
  (elpy-enable))
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(jedi use-package gnu-elpa-keyring-update elpy)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

First issue is the following:
In the output of M-x elpy-config RET below it says that "jedi: Not found". Even after

installing it via pip and restart emacs and also
installing it via the [Install jedi] in the same buffer (Elpy Config), which completed the installation.
Also did: [Update python packages] (in the Elpy Config buffer)

Still, problem persists, it cannot find the installation when I restart emacs and do M-x elpy-config RET ... it still says "jedi: Not found"
What am I doing wrong?

PS. My pip packages:
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 27.1
Elpy..............: Not found (Python), 1.35.0 (Emacs Lisp)
Virtualenv........: emacs-venv (/home/ytsen/emacs-venv)
Interactive Python: python3 3.10.12 (/home/ytsen/emacs-venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/ytsen/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python nil (/home/ytsen/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: Not found
 Rope.............: Not found
 Autopep8.........: Not found
 Yapf.............: Not found
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/ytsen/emacs-venv/bin/flake8)

Warnings

The Python interpreter could not find the elpy module. Please report
to: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/new.

There was an unexpected problem starting the RPC process. Please check
the following output to see if this makes sense to you. To me, it
doesn't.

<string>:3: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
{"can_connect_to_pypi": true, "rpc_python_version": "3.10.12", "elpy_version": "1.35.0", "jedi_version": "0.19.1", "jedi_latest": null, "rope_version": "1.13.0", "rope_latest": null, "autopep8_version": "2.3.1", "autopep8_latest": null, "yapf_version": "0.40.2", "yapf_latest": null, "black_version": "24.10.0", "black_latest": null}

Elpy could not connect to Pypi (or at least not quickly enough) and
check if the python packages were up-to-date. You can still try to
update all of them:

[Update python packages]

The Jedi package is not currently installed. This package is needed
for code completion, code navigation and access to documentation.


(emacs-venv) ytsen@y7:~$ pip freeze
autopep8==2.3.1
black==24.10.0
click==8.1.7
elpy==1.999
flake8==7.1.1
importlib_metadata==8.5.0
jedi==0.19.1
mccabe==0.7.0
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
packaging==24.1
parso==0.8.4
pathspec==0.12.1
platformdirs==4.3.6
pycodestyle==2.12.1
pyflakes==3.2.0
tomli==2.0.2
typing_extensions==4.12.2
yapf==0.40.2
zipp==3.20.2



Too difficult because of outdated manuals, unless you are an Emacs/Lisp expert.
So I abandoned the project above with my system default Emacs and I did the following which got me what I wanted:
I installed Emacs 29.4 where I compiled from source.
Then updated my init.el with MELPA package server:
(require 'package)
;; Any add to list for package-archives (to add marmalade or melpa) goes here
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("MELPA" .
      "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

Then used that to install lsp-mode: M-x package-install RET lsp-mode RET.
Then added to my init.el:
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)

(use-package lsp-ui :commands lsp-ui-mode)

After that installed in via M-x package-install RET:
lsp-ui for fancy sideline, popup documentation, VScode-like peek UI, etc.
flycheck if you prefer the more popular flycheck over renewed flymake. lsp-mode will automatically pick it up.
company-mode for completion popups.
lsp-treemacs for various tree based UI controls (symbols, errors overview, call hierarchy, etc.)

Then quit Emacs and installed on my system the following via pip:
  python -m pip install  'python-lsp-server[all]'

This was what finally got my what I needed.
